# How to set vertical scrollbar in Listview in xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am loaded the data in List view in my page. I am able to scroll the data in List view but at the time of scrolling not showing any scrollbar at vertical. Please suggest any idea, How can I set vertical scrollbar in List view.

Sample code:

```
<ListView BackgroundColor="Transparent" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
ItemsSource="{Binding DataList}" HeightRequest="{Binding DataListRowHeight}" HasUnevenRows="true" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" RowHeight="40" SeparatorColor="Transparent"
SelectedItem="null">
                  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                      <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="0,0,0,0">
                          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                          <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemClicked"/>
                          </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                          <Label Text="{Binding WindowName}" Grid.Column="0" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Avenir Book" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">                                
                          </Label>
                          <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column= "1">
                            <Label Text="Curtain Type:" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Avenir Book" FontAttributes="Bold" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">                                
                            </Label>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Data}" TextColor="Black" FontFamily="Avenir Book" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" VerticalTextAlignment="Center">                                  
                            </Label>
                          </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                      </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Above is the second listview sample code.

Comment: Could you share the XMAL how you set the second listview?

Comment: I have added my sample code, Can you look at once.

Comment: This code is no problem , attach the complete code (include the first listview )  and provide the method how to set the DataListRowHeight